# Create EVP_CIPHER_CTX array

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm using CentOS 7 and OpenSSL v1.1.0.

Since OpenSSL changed their API, I got the following error: `invalid use of incomplete type struct evp_cipher_ctx_st`.

```
static void InitAESKey(AES_KEY_CTX* ctx, BYTE* keybytes, int numkeys)
        {
                BYTE* pBufIdx = keybytes;
                for (int i = 0; i < numkeys; i++)
                {
                        OTEXT_AES_KEY_INIT(ctx + i, pBufIdx);
                        pBufIdx += AES_KEY_BYTES;
                }
        }
```

While `AES_KEY_CTX` and `OTEXT_AES_KEY_INIT` are macros defined:

```
#define AES_KEY_CTX EVP_CIPHER_CTX
#define OTEXT_AES_KEY_INIT(ctx, buf) { \
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(ctx); \
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, buf, ZERO_IV); \
        }
```

I tried to change the macro to `#define AES_KEY_CTX EVP_CIPHER_CTX*`, but the error still exist.

Comment: Use [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption). When using EVP interface, the Key and IV are set in the call to `EVP_EncryptInit_ex`.

Comment: @jww this what I'm using. The problem is this operation `ctx + i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I consulted with OpenSSL users email list, I made this changes in order the code to compiled:

```
#define AES_KEY_CTX *EVP_CIPHER_CTX;
static void InitAESKey(AES_KEY_CTX* ctx, BYTE* keybytes, int numkeys)
{
    BYTE* pBufIdx = keybytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < numkeys; i++)
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(*(ctx + i));
        EVP_EncryptInit_ex(*(ctx + i), EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, pBufIdx, ZERO_IV);
        pBufIdx += AES_KEY_BYTES;
    }
}
```